# Structure Dynamic TestCafe runs

Tags: testing, automated-tests, roles, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to test that multiple types of users (separated out into roles) can log in and view a listing page and each applicable type of filter. Since it's redundant to write this `N` times for every user compounded by every filter I'm using the following:

```
export const filters = {
  typeOne: {
    'Alerts': 'alerts',
    'Open': 'open',
    'Pending': 'pending',
    'Finished': 'finished',
    'Closed': 'closed'
  },
  /* ... */
}

export const roleTitles = {
  typeOne: 'User Type One',
  typeTwo: 'User Type Two',
  /* ... */
}

const getSelectorMenuItem = (label) => Selector('.marketplace-side-nav.menu').find('.item').withText(label)
const selectorMap = Selector('.map-container')
const selectorMarketplaceList = Selector('.marketplace-list')

Object.keys(roles).map(async (role) => {
  await Promise.all(Object.keys(filters[role]).map(async (filterTitle) => {
    test(`${roleTitles[role]} Can open ${filterTitle} filter`, async t => {
      const expectedPath = `marketplace/all/${filters[role][filterTitle]}`
      await t.useRole(roles[role])
        .click(getSelectorMenuItem(filterTitle))
        .expect(getLocation()).contains(expectedPath, { timeout: 3000 })
        .expect(selectorMap.exists).ok()
        .expect(selectorMarketplaceList.exists).ok()
      })
  }))
})
```

This works, however, it is extremely slow. I'm not foreign to the fact that e2e tests take time, but it seems to hang once it reaches the last element in any of the filter types.

Comment: Just messing with this some more, the issue seemed to be running `useRole` every time and not taking advantage of already being in the correct view.
Hoisting the `t.useRole` above the `Promise.all` then `t.click...` actions inside of that was (obviously) exponentially more performant.

Comment: It's difficult to say something definite.
I guess that most of the time is taken by things that are not related to dynamic test runs and role switching.
I can look for a problem if you provide a simple example showing this issue.